# How to execute a python code on clicking a button on html page and show the results on the same page in Django?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I made a plain simple search page using this [tutorial](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/searchengine).
This works nicely and I get the search results as a list of clickable links.

Now, I want that on clicking a link (one of the search result), one of my python function is run in `views.py` and the output is shown in the same page.

For example, suppose the search result is like this,

**Results**

[result1][1]

[result2][2]

then upon clicking 'result1', my python code is run in the backend:

`def mypythoncode(a_search_result):
   output = a_search_result + ' processed output'
   return output`

and the returned output is shown on the same search result page as:

**Results**

[result1][1]

result1 processed output

[result2][2]

For this, I was trying to make the search result output as buttons using this,

```
<button id="{{ res.0 }}">{{ res.0 }}</button>
```

I can easily make the button look like a URL hyperlink, so for my purpose this is fine.

I do not know how to click on this "button" (the search result), run a python in backend, and render the results in the same `search.html` page.

I am new to Django. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by using Ajax. Using the on click event of the button, call your **search function** url. Make sure the function returns a JSON response.

Response can be displayed on the UI without reloading the page. A response would look like multiple objects that can be parsed easily in Javascript.

[Ajax + Django](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/AJAX)  <- great set of resources for the same.

Comment: Thank you! I am going through the links to understand.